# How to resume partial downloads using transmission?

Tags: downloads

Can we resume partial torrent downloads using the default transmission software?
I started 500 mb download which was downloaded half way. Now I can't seem to resume the download.

Comment: Please go to the folder you have selected to download the files then _edit_ your question and add it's contents.

Answer (score 3):

`Transmission` should verify the local data automatically when the torrent started again. In case you have moved the data on another folder, you can use the `set location` option and point to the folder where the file is. (not the torrent file but the actual file - music,movie,iso whatever).

So, first attempt would be:

remove the torrent (not the data, the torrent file only) from transmission and add it again. It should check the data and resume automatically. Be aware that the torrent file should be exactly the same. If you don't have it, download the torrent file again(from the same site).

second attempt:

Add the torrent file manually to transmission and stop it. Then right click on that file and click the `set location`. Browse and point to the folder where the actual file is. Then click the `verify local data` option and wait until complete. Then start the download again.